# QML scaling extremely slow

Tags: qt, qml, scale

I'm currently working on a project where I need to scale the whole UI based on a global scale factor. I have about 2000 Items (and yes, I need that much). For now, those are just simple `Rectangle`, but the will get more complex later. I simulated the final behavior by adding5 rectangles inside each of the "main rectangles".

The problem is, if I change the scale factor, it takes about 3 seconds until the change is done. In this 3 seconds, the application freezes.

It tried different ways of using the scale:

Direct for all scalable properties:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 50 * global.scale
    height: 50 * global.scale
}
```

Using the `scale` property:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    scale: global.scale
}
```

However, both of them are equally slow. So, is there a way to zoom the whole ui with having to resize every element? Or anything else, that makes it faster?

Comment: What kind of items are they?

Comment: Just as I said, in my test project they are `Rectangle`, but later they will be a compisition of multiple elemens, e.g Rectangles, Labels, ...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that part. What hardware is the application running on?

Comment: Does the scaling happen often, or just once at startup?

Comment: Often, since the user needs to constantly zoom in and out. It's running on a computer, and since mine is a gaming PC, the hardware is good enough

Comment: Are you by any chance using an Angle build?

Comment: How does this example run for you? http://pastebin.com/EsRVpc0z

Comment: That example runs - but after increasing the number of elements to 10000 (and thats what happens if I use the real elements) it still hangs

Comment: @ddriver How can I determine that? Im using msvc2013 64bit, the default one you can download from the Qt website

Comment: @ddriver I googled and found out how to explicitly set/check those. The result: I'm using opengl. I tested both, but there is almost no difference

Comment: @Felix - running a little test here: http://pastebin.com/3srn8jyy - that's 40 000 rectangles, although the creation takes a 3-4 seconds, resizing them all takes about half a second on my machine. Test your machine with that, if the result is OK then maybe your code is not as simple as rectangles.

Comment: Same for me... Well, seems thats really the case. I will look into my code and try to find whatever kind of element causes the slow down

Comment: @Felix - it is not the evaluation of expressions either, I tried using an expression, the performance is the same. You have a QML profiler - use it, it will show you where is the overhead.

Comment: I found the reason... Im using a `GridLayout` - and for whatever reason, it's extremly slow if modify one of the `Layout.*` attatched properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answere was quite simple: Using the debug build can be very slow, but as soon as I started a release build, it worked just fine.